# HTML file to screenshot as .jpg or other image

Tags: html, linux, image, screenshot, jpeg

Nothing to do with rendering an individual image on a webpage.  Goal is to render the entire webpage save that as a screenshot.  Want to show a thumbnail of an HTML file to the user.  The HTML file I will be screenshotting will be an HTML part in a MIME email message - ideally I would like to snapshot the entire MIME file but if I can do this to an HTML file I'll be in good shape.

An API would be ideal but an executable is also good.

Comment: That would require rendering, I think, and your question is just a little bit confusing, there are a few image libraries out there, what language are you using?

Comment: So...you want to *render* the HTML file -- to a JPEG, presumably, based on your tags -- and display it as a thumbnail.  Right?  Also, what is a "MIME file"?  Do you mean a MIME-encoded email message?

Comment: Edited for clarity.  And, yes, I will have a MIME-encoded email message which among other things will have an HTML part.  If someone happens to know a technology that does this to a MIME email that would be great, but it's more realistic to ask for the HTML part -> screenshot.

Comment: One suggestion would be to generate a PDF from the HTML and use the PDF instead of the image.

A quick way to do this on Linux is via wkhtmltopdf (http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)

Comment: yeah, I have that working.  currently trying to get wkhtmltoimage to work, it keeps returning 127 and doing nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going with wkhtmltoimage.  This worked once correctly set up xvfb.  The postscript suggestion did not render correctly and we need img not pdf.

Answer (score 1):

You need html2ps, and convert from the package ImageMagick:

```
html2ps index.html index.ps 
convert index.ps index.png
```

The second program produces one png per page for a long html-page - the page layout was done by by html2ps.

I found a program evince-thumbnailer, which was reported as:

```
apropos postscript | grep -i png 
evince-thumbnailer (1) - create png thumbnails from PostScript and PDF documents
```

but it didn't work on an simple, first test.

If you like to combine multiple pages to a larger image, convert will help you surely.

Now I see, that convert operates on html directly, so

```
convert index.html index.png
```

shall work too. I don't see a difference in the output, and the size of the images is nearly identical.

If you have a multipart mime-type email, you typically have a mail header, maybe some pre-html-text, the html and maybe attachments.

You can extract the html and format it seperately - but rendering it embedded might not be that easy.

Here is a file I tested, which was from Apr. 14, so I extract the one mail from the mailfolder:

```
sed -n "/From - Sat Apr 14/,/From -/p" /home/stefan/.mozilla-thunderbird/k2jbztqu.default/Mail/Local\ Folders-1/Archives.sbd/sample | \
sed -n '/<html>/,/<\/html>/p' | wkhtmltopdf - - > sample.pdf
```

then I extract just the html-part of that.

wkhtmltopdf needs `- -`  for reading stdin/writing to stdout. The PDF is rendered, but I don't know how to integrate it into your workflow.

You can replace `wkhtml ...` with

```
 convert - sample.jpg
```

Comment: This solution looks good so far, I'll need to play with it more before accepting.  It seems XWindows-independent and all of my problems so far have centered around that, in some form or another.

Comment: No...  the PS looks very little like the original page, and the entire process takes several seconds (this app is performance sensitive).

Comment: @djechlin: Is the html-page online? May I ask for the adress?

Comment: will be using on a variety of emails, if I can get it to work fine for http://google.com/ that would be a start

Comment: You want to do it for foreign websites, which are online? Or to emails, which you have open in your Email-client? Did you test "print to PDF"? I don't know how fast this is, but for interactive programs, I would expect 2-3 seconds to be ok. On my 8 y'o laptops, a 13 pages html with text and images is processed in 2.5s. Would pdf be an alternative?